# Axios.get returns plain html intead of JSON return data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, axios

I'm new to react js and trying to get the data from the database using `axios.get` when componentDidmount. This is the request I'm trying to get the products. I'm using react with laravel.

```
componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/getproducts')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            });
    }
```

In Controller I'm returning the data

```
public function products()
    {
       $products = Product::all();
       return response()->json($products);
    }
```

After returning the response in `axios.get` I get the below plain HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Learn React</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://localhost:8000/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="crud-app"></div>

       <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Web.php

```
<?php


Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any','.*');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('save-product', 'ProductController@saveProduct')->name('save.product');
Route::get('getproducts', 'ProductController@products')->name('get.products');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the api urls to the top of the php file and it is best practice to add 'api/' as the prefix

```
<?php

Route::post('api/save-product', 'ProductController@saveProduct')->name('save.product');
Route::get('api/getproducts', 'ProductController@products')->name('get.products');


Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any','.*');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: why its not working before when the routes is below ?

Comment: This issue occurs because the php file runs line by line from top. So if the first line says to forward all requests to "welcome" view. then it does that and return.

Comment: the working of returning view welcome route will work fine in this case ?

Comment: yes, if non of the above urls match. So in this case welcome view becomes a fallback view

Answer (score 1):

Pass addition settings in Axios.get() HTTP call

```
export const axiosConfig = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "APITOKEN": API_TOKEN
    }
};

 axios.get('http://localhost:8000/getproducts',axiosConfig)
            .then(response => {
   console.log(response.data);
 });
```

Comment: You can ignore the APITOKEN parameter if you don't have.

Comment: Ok so the problem is in your laravel api response.

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: public function products()
    {
       $products = Product::all();
       return response()->json($products)->->header('Content-Type','application/json');
    }

Try this hope this solution works.

Comment: i got the some research when i put my routes in routes/api.php and call route like this localhost:8000/api/getproducts its works.. what the issue ?

Comment: So you write the route in routes/api.php so you need to call api too.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a setting of your server because the get response is directed to your react app instead of your api endpoint. Try hosting your api on another port and have axios request that url port instead.

Comment: In laravel where should i change to get this working?

Comment: i did  some research when i put my routes in routes/api.php and call route like this localhost:8000/api/getproducts its works.. what the issue ?

Comment: This is because the get request resolved to the react app first before reaching your api endpoint and hence returning the html like a normal browsing instead of a rest API call

Answer (score 0):

If you are using API call then you have to change your URL like below:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/getproducts
```

Comment: i changed but it still gettnig the same html

Comment: what is your API route? @ArslanAkram

Comment: i am writing my routes in web.php and this is my route 
Route::get('getproducts', 'ProductController@products')->name('get.products');

Comment: i did some research when i put my routes in routes/api.php and call route like this localhost:8000/api/getproducts its works.. what the issue why its not working in web.php ?

Comment: Are you using API or WEB? front-end and back-end is in same or using different platform? @ArslanAkram

Comment: Sir actually i am using first time react with laravel.. i am using axios.get to get products from database. i write my urls in web.php but when i use axios.get its working but when i use axios.get its return the home page html.

Comment: yes it is in the same project. frontend is from react components

Comment: @ArslanAkram I think this is you have to write                                                            componentDidMount(){
       axios.get(MyGlobleSetting.url + '/api/products')
       .then(response => {
         this.setState({ products: response.data });
       })  and have to use API response in that and bind it with render() with html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204533/discussion-between-karan-khimani-and-arslan-akram).

Comment: check above ans @ArslanAkram

Answer (score -1):

```
       axios.get(MyGlobleSetting.url + '/api/products')
       .then(response => {
         this.setState({ products: response.data });
       })
       .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
       })
     }




render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Products</h1>


        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-10"></div>
          <div className="col-md-2">
            <Link to="/add-item">Create Product</Link>
          </div>
        </div><br />


        <table className="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Product Title</td>
                <td>Product Body</td>
                <td width="200px">Actions</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.tabRow()}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
export default DisplayProduct;
```

Answer (score -1):

just add "/" at the end url like this

from
"http://localhost:8000/getproducts"
to
"http://localhost:8000/getproducts/"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).